# can not update view "routines" in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, view

I have a database with almost 400 functions in PostgreSQL. Among them many functions have RAISE INFO for debug purpose . Now I want to comment this RAISE INFO in all the functions. For that I use below query:

```
UPDATE information_schema.routines SET routine_definition = REPLACE(routine_definition,'RAISE','-- RAISE') WHERE (routine_definition) like '%RAISE%'
```

But it gives me below error:

```
ERROR: cannot update view "routines"
SQL state: 55000
Detail: Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
Hint: To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule.
```

I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [pg_proc.prosrc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html), although I'd be concerned about altering other RAISE statements too with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Richard Huxton**

Here is the Details query for reference:

```
 UPDATE pg_proc SET prosrc = REPLACE(prosrc,'RAISE','-- RAISE') WHERE (prosrc) like '%RAISE%'
```